# Let $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n}$ be a Markov chain on a finite state space $S$ with transition probabilities $p_{x y}$.

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, heat-equation

I am struggling with this question and the solutions don't seem to help me much:

**Question**

Let $\left(X_{n}\right)_{n}$ be a Markov chain on a finite state space $S$ with transition probabilities $p_{x y}$. Suppose $a$ is absorbing and that all other states are transient. Find the minimal nonnegative solution $h$ of the system
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
h(a) &=1 \\
h(x) &=p_{x a}+\sum_{y \in S} p_{x y} h(y), \quad x \neq a
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
Express $h$ in its simplest form.

**Solution**

$h(x)=P_{x a}+\sum_{y \in S} P_{x y} h(y)$ where we know  $x \neq a$

$$K_{i}^{A}=E_{i}\left(H^{A}\right)=\sum_{n=\infty} n P_{x y}\left(H^{A}=n\right)+\infty\left(H^{A}=\infty\right)$$

$$h_{a}^{i}=P_{a}(h_{\text{heat equation}})$$

$$h_{i}=\frac{(q / p)^{i}-(q / p)^{N}}{1-(2 \mid p)^{N}}$$
$$h_{i}=A+B_{i}$$
$$h_{i}=1-{i / N}$$
$$h_{(x)}=\sum_{j \in A} P_{x q}=\sum_{j \in A} P_{i} j x_{j}$$

I am confused as to how does the heat equation come into play here. As far as I was going about this question it seems like the drunkard's walk? But then the states in that were recurrent so I dont understand the solutions exactly.

Comment: I don't think the solution is right. The question is asking something else.

Comment: In the equation for $h(X)$, could the sum be over $y\in S$ with $y\neq a$ by any chance? Also, could you give us the source of the question?

Answer (score 1):

Just think about the definition of $h$, $h(a) = P(Ending~up~at~a|being~at~a) = 1$, for the others it's a little more complicated.
$$h(x) = h(a)\cdot P(moving~to~a) + \sum_{y \in S,y \ne a}{h(y)\cdot P(moving~to~y)}$$
$h(x)$ is exaclty the probability that you will end up at `state a` eventually. Since a is the only absorbing state and other states are transient, this is trivially $h(x)=1 (\forall x \in S)$